# Unable to fix Real Time Permissions with Ubuntu Studio Control

Tags: sound, permissions, ubuntu-studio, realtime

*What I expected to happen:* Use the Ubuntu Studio Control app to set up real time (low latency) permissions

*What happened instead:* When I click the button to fix real time permissions, it gives me a long error message asking me to undo "custom changes." What is it talking about, and how can I get more information to troubleshoot this?

*Context:* I recently installed the Ubuntu studio meta-packages. Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with backports PPA. I couldn't find any specific documentation relating to this, just vague mentions to past procedures involving adding the user to the audio group.

My end goal is to use looping music apps, so low latency is a priority. Thanks!

Comment: Did you install the low-latency kernel? Usually, you have to install the low latency kernel and then, when you boot Ubuntu, you can select the low latency kernel from the grub menu. Also, please post the specific error so that we know what you are talking about. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I was booting from the low latency Kernel, and I had restarted a few times with no effect. I wish I had screenshotted the error because, fortunately for me, Ubuntu Studio Controls now says "Real Time Permissions Enabled." Thank you for your comment!

Comment: I have the same problem. I installed Ubuntu Studio 22.04 fresh and am not aware of having made any "custom changes" to the audio system. I have no audio at all, so I desperately need to troubleshoot this problem!

Comment: Rebooting and starting QJACKctl seems to have resolved the message in Ubuntu Studio Control.  However, I still have no sound and haven't found ayn way to troubleshoot the problem.  https://frontpagelinux.com/tutorials/ubuntu-studio-20-10-audio-setup-tutorial/ involves many tools that I do not (yet) need or want to use: I can't even get sounds for system notifications.